# Enity Framework updating with a child table causing errors

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following update function

```
public void UpdateBatchDefinition(BatchDefinition batchToUpdate)
{
    if (batchToUpdate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("batchToUpdate");
    }

    BatchDefinition foundDefinition =
            this.context.BatchDefinitions.SingleOrDefault(definition => definition.Id == batchToUpdate.Id);

    if (foundDefinition != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(batchToUpdate.Name))
        {
            foundDefinition.Name = batchToUpdate.Name;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(batchToUpdate.Description))
        {
            foundDefinition.Description = batchToUpdate.Description;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(batchToUpdate.LoadType))
        {
            foundDefinition.LoadType = batchToUpdate.LoadType;
        }

        if (batchToUpdate.JobId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            foundDefinition.JobId = batchToUpdate.JobId;
        }

        foundDefinition.Tables = batchToUpdate.Tables;
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

the issue I am having Is when I am trying to update the Tables list. Tables is a List of Table and Table is a Entity of another table

Tables could be added to, removed from or left alone. I need to update that with what ever is being passed in

when I run this right now I get an 'EntityValidationErrors' error, though it wont tell me what the validation issue actually is.

on Inserting I got the same error but was able to fix it using the following

```
var underlyingContext = this.context as DbContext;
if (underlyingContext != null)
{
    foreach (var table in batchDefinition.Tables)
    {
        // Need to mark the table entity as unchanged or 
        // else EF will treat it as a new table
        underlyingContext.Entry(table).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

so I tried using that in this update function

```
var underlyingContext = this.context as DbContext;
if (underlyingContext != null)
{
    foreach (var table in foundDefinition.Tables)
    {
        // Need to mark the table entity as unchanged or 
        //else EF will treat it as a new table
        underlyingContext.Entry(table).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}

foundDefinition.Tables = batchToUpdate.Tables;
```

and I get the following error instead:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key
>   values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Any thoughts one what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change end of your update method like this:

```
foreach (var t in foundDefinition.Tables.ToList())
    Context.Tables.Remove(t);

foundDefinition.Tables = batchToUpdate.Tables;
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

And about your last error, it is said that there are some duplicates in your context. So, EF can't save the context changes into the db (because there are duplicates in the context!)

In fact, I don't know the last error is from add or delete - you didn't mention clearly. So, I don't know the last two code samples are from your add method, or your update method...

However for update, the trick I mentioned here, must solve your problem for update...